# spring boot interface left join return just one record, while it contains many

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, jpa, jdbc

```
table(model{m_id,name} and table role_model{id,m_id,name,status}
```

here there is 3 rows in the model and 1 row in the role_model so it must be like this

```
1   UserManagement  NULL    21      0       1       TEST    1    
2   RoleManagement  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
3   Configurations  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

this is the interface

```
@Query(value="SELECT * FROM model as m LEFT JOIN role_model as rm on(m.m_id =rm.m_id)",
       nativeQuery = true) 
     List<Model> ListJoined();
```

this is the service implementation:

```
 public List<Model> listJoined(){
   return repo.ListJoined();
 }
```

in controller rest api

```
@GetMapping("/test")
public String test(){  
    return service.listJoined();
}
```

this is returning only one record

1   UserManagement  NULL    21      0       1       TEST    1

Answer (score 0):

Hi please check this example

```
 String GET_MODEL_LIST = "SELECT * FROM model AS m LEFT JOIN role_model AS rm ON m.m_id =rm.m_id";

 @Query(GET_MODEL_LIST) 
 List<Model> ListJoined();
```

Please read this article, if you are using jpa without typing a query, you can join through methods.
https://www.amitph.com/spring-data-jpa-query-methods/